# IndexError: list index out of range // numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying define a procedure that calculates mean of daily returns for every security:

```
def Adj_mean():
    return np.loadtxt('my_file.csv', skiprows=1, usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6)).mean(axis=0)
```

Here is `my_file.csv`:

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close           Volume    Adj Close
2013-09-27  874.82  877.52  871.31  876.39  1258800    876.39
2013-09-26  878.3   882.75  875 878.17  1259900        878.17
2013-09-25  886.55  886.55  875.6   877.23  1649000    877.23
2013-09-24  886.5   890.1   881.4   886.84  1467000    886.84
2013-09-23  896.15  901.59  885.2   886.5   1777400    886.5
2013-09-20  898.39  904.13  895.62  903.11  4345300    903.11
2013-09-19  905.99  905.99  895.4   898.39  1597900    898.39
2013-09-18  886.35  903.97  883.07  903.32  1934700    903.32
2013-09-17  887.41  888.39  881 886.11  1259400        886.11
2013-09-16  896.2   897 884.87  887.76  1336500        887.76
```

When i run it:

```
print Adj_mean()
```

I have the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

**NOTE:** daily return formula: **(x - y)/y** or  **(x / y) - 1** ; where x = today Adj close, and y = yesterday Adj close

Comment: could it be that cols is starting from index 0 and not 1?

Comment: The code runs and gives `array([  8.89666000e+02,   8.93799000e+02,   8.82847000e+02,   8.88382000e+02,   1.78859000e+06,   8.88382000e+02])`. Give us a reproducible sample.

Comment: yes - this code is working for me and gives: [  8.89666000e+02   8.93799000e+02   8.82847000e+02   8.88382000e+02
   1.78859000e+06   8.88382000e+02]

Comment: You'll get the exception `IndexError: list index out of range` if one of the lines in the file has fewer than seven columns.  Is the sample file that you've shown exactly the same as the file you use when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Check your *.csv file, the last line does not have value for `Adj Close` column. The last line in these stock history data downloaded from Google finance represent the *first* day in the dataset. Based on your daily return formula, the first day does not have value.